# Como iterar com uma table em Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Como iterar com uma *table* em `Lua`?

Exemplo:

```
dados = {
    nome = 'Wallace',
    idade = 25
}
```

Comment: Agora que está aprendendo Lua, dê uma olhada em todas as perguntas da *tag*, tem muita coisa que já foi respondida. Agora que eu achei esta. E não esqueça de votar em tudo o que é bom que for achando em todas s perguntas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
dados = {
    nome = 'Wallace',
    idade = 25
}
for k, v in pairs(dados) do
    print(k, "=>", v)
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i2NzXh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lasrbgrb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TableIteration.lua).

Comment: Eu estava vendo que tem um tal de `foreach`, `foreachi` e `foreachvar`. Isso é em versões antigas?

Comment: Mostre onde está vendo isto, eu desconheço.

Comment: http://www.fabricadigital.com.br/media/Curso_Lua.pdf

Comment: Note que são funções e não comandos. O comando é o `for`. As funções pode ser usadas, claro, eles receberão *lambdas* como parâmetros. A semântica da função é um pouco diferente do comando, mas resolve bem a maioria das situações. Em geral eu evitaria. Isto é quase o mesmo que preferir jQuery ao JS :)